# Define and query multiple values field in Elasticsearch using NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I would like to index documents in Elasticsearch with a multiple values field (not multifield) using NEST. Consider the following data:

```
{
     "id": "someid",
     "name": "name 1",
     "name": "name 2",
     "name": "name 3"
}
```

The Lucene query I'm looking to write should look something like this:

```
name:"name 2"
```

This query should search all of the name fields. How to do this using NEST?

Comment: Why don't you want to use multifield?

Comment: Firstly copy & paste the entirety of your JSON into http://jsonlint.com/ and validate, look at the outcome

Comment: If multifield solves my problem, I don't mind using that. But I don't want to search through multiple fields here. I want to be able to index a name x times and search through all of the names.

Comment: I don't need to validate my json, cause this is valid input for Elasticsearch according to their documentation.

Comment: @ThomasArdal `IEnumerable<string> Name { get; set; }` is not an option here?

Comment: Maybe. Can I do a lucene Query on that: name:"Thomas" ?

Comment: yes thats what @NSMeef meant with multi valued fields :) You can search that Name field just as you would a `string Name { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can query using multi_match query as follows

```
{"multi_match":{"query":"java","fields":["*"]}}]}}
```